# Could not able to compile with /opt/ELDK42/usr/bin/ppc-linux-g++

Tags: 14.04, gcc, c++, compiler

here is my test.cpp

```
#include<iostream>
    using namespace std;
    int main()
    {
     cout<<"hello world";
     return 0;
    }



 $ /opt/ELDK42/usr/bin/ppc-linux-g++ test.cpp
```

Compilation Errors:

```
test.cpp:1:19: error: iostream: No such file or directory
test.cpp: In function 'int main()':
test.cpp:10: error: 'cout' was not declared in this scope
```

Why it Could not able to fetch iostream from any include directories?
So,I tried compiling by explicitly including

```
/opt/ELDK42/usr/bin/ppc_85xx-g++ test.cpp -I/opt/ELDK42/ppc_85xx/usr/include/c++/4.2.2/
```

Then, it gave the following errors:

```
In file included from test.cpp:1:
/opt/ELDK42/ppc_85xx/usr/include/c++/4.2.2/iostream:44:28: error: bits/c++config.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /opt/ELDK42/ppc_85xx/usr/include/c++/4.2.2/ios:43,
                 from /opt/ELDK42/ppc_85xx/usr/include/c++/4.2.2/ostream:45,
                 from /opt/ELDK42/ppc_85xx/usr/include/c++/4.2./iostream:45,
```

But, i could see that missing header file here:

```
/opt/ELDK42/ppc_85xx/usr/include/c++/4.2.2/powerpc-linux/bits/c++config.h
```

> I am not able to figure out, why gcc is not able to find the header
>   files properly & compile??

Is it anything to do with ELDK version?

Any help, highly appreciated.

**System Details:**
Ubuntu 14.04
gcc 4.2.2

Comment: Do the built-in include paths of the `ppc_85xx-g++` binary reflect the actual install location of the headers within the toolchain tree? You can check using the methods discussed in this [so] answer [Dump include paths from g++](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11946295/4440445). If not, you may need to specify the locations explicitly - via a `CPPFLAGS` environment variable for example.

Comment: @Karel, I seen the link u mentioned, it's different. btw, I tried solution mentioned there, it's not the case here...

Comment: @steeldriver, useful link.
     I checked  /opt/ELDK42/usr/bin/ppc-linux-g++ -E -x c++ - -v < /dev/null

       It showed following  paths:     
/opt/ELDK42/usr//../ppc_85xx/usr/include
        /opt/ELDK42/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/powerpc-linux/4.2.2/include

     First path is having header files, but gcc says, no such file or directory.
        /opt/ELDK42/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/powerpc-linux/4.2.2/include